# Python combinations using lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers

I am wondering how would you get all possible combinations from as list.

```
list1 = [1,5,3]
```

This should return:

```
ans = [1,5,3,15,13,51,53,31,35,153,135,315,351,531,513]
```

Thanks for the replies
Adam

Comment: Are they all integers? what have you tried already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Answer (score 2):

You want the [permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), not the [combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) :

```
from itertools import permutations

list1 = [1,5,3]
n = len(list1)

print([int("".join(map(str, ints))) for i in range(n)
       for ints in permutations(list1, i + 1)])
# [1, 5, 3, 15, 13, 51, 53, 31, 35, 153, 135, 513, 531, 315, 351]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do it like that:

```
import itertools
import operator
import numpy as np
a=[1,2,3]
[list(i) for i in reduce(operator.add,[list(itertools.combinations(a,i)) for i in range(1,len(a)+1)])]
```

Then the result is

```
[[1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

If you want it to have the exact format you listed in the question, you can do

```
import itertools
import operator
import numpy as np
a=[1,2,3]
a=[str(i) for i in a]
[int(''.join(list(i))) for i in reduce(operator.add,[list(itertools.combinations(a,i)) for i in range(1,len(a)+1)])]
```

The result is

```
[1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 23, 123]
```

Answer (score 0):

by brute force:

```
import random

list1 = [1,5,3]
brute = 1000

combos = []
for i in range(brute):
    random.shuffle(list1)
    z = ''.join(str(x) for x in list1)
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        combos.append(int(z[i:]))
combos = sorted(list(set(combos)))
print combos




>>>[1, 3, 5, 13, 15, 31, 35, 51, 53, 135, 153, 315, 351, 513, 531]
```